# Minify error after vite build with react-dropzone-uploader

Tags: reactjs, vite

I have migrate my app from cra to vite but now my dropzone uploader is not working and return me this error **only in production**

Its look like the error come from the Dropzone component but I can't explain why it work fine in development and was working with CRA

error:
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #130; visit [https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]=](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args%5B%5D=object&args%5B%5D=) for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

component:

```
import Dropzone from "react-dropzone-uploader";
import api from "../../../Service/API/API";

import {lang} from "../../../Service/Translator";
import "../../../App.css"

export function UploadBox({update, closeAfterUpload, onClose, body, url, disabled}) {

   const getUploadParams = ({file, meta}) => {
      const body = new FormData()
      for (let k of Object.keys(body)) {
         body.append(k, body[k])
      }

      body.append('title', file.name.split(".")[0])
      body.append('file', file)

      return {
         url: `${api.getURL()}${url ? url : 'user/files'}`,
         body: body,
         field: {},
         headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${api.Auth.getAccessToken()}`},
         meta: meta
      }
   }

   // called every time a file's `status` changes
   const handleChangeStatus = ({meta, file, xhr}, status) => {
      if (status === 'done') {
         let response = JSON.parse(xhr.response)
         meta.id = response.id

         api.snackAction(lang.UploadSucceed.replace('{0}', meta.name), "success")

         update ? update() : null

         if (closeAfterUpload) {
            onClose()
         }
      } else if (status === 'aborted') {
         api.snackAction(lang.UploadAborted.replace('{0}', meta.name), "warning")

      } else if (status === 'error_upload') {
         api.snackAction(lang.UploadError.replace('{0}', meta.name), "error")

      } else if (status === 'rejected_file_type') {
         api.snackAction(lang.UploadRejectedFileType, "Warning")

      } else if (status === 'removed') {
         api.Enterprise
            .Files
            .delete(meta.id)
            .then(() => {
               update ? update() : null
            })

      }

   }

   return (
      <div>
         <Dropzone
            disabled={disabled}
            body={body}
            getUploadParams={getUploadParams}
            onChangeStatus={handleChangeStatus}
            classNames={"preview_darkmode"}
            maxSizeBytes={Math.pow(2, 30)}
            // onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            accept="image/*,.pdf"
         />

      </div>
   );

}
```

Comment: Hi Victor,
did you manage to resolve this by any chance?

Answer (score 4):

by me i create following file and use DropzoneFix component, and works:

```
// DropzoneFix.tsx
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone-uploader';
function fixComponent<T>(component: T): T {
    return (component as any).default ?? component;
}
export const DropzoneFix = fixComponent(Dropzone);
```